# How much digital information can a piece of paper hold, assuming you write to it with a modern printer and read from it with a modern scanner?

Tags: printing, datastore

I realize this is sort of an open question, so to clarify, I want an answer which gives an error rate approaching the error rate of alternative storage media.

Inspired by [this ad from the 90s](https://i.redd.it/7ek2amf1s0rz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ad you link to appears to be comparing the capacity of a data CD to that of *text* printed on paper.  You can store data on paper much more compactly than as text, but let's start there.

Suppose we're talking about black, monospaced, 8-pitch, English text at 6/lines per inch, with no margins.  Supposing also that we get to choose a font for the purpose, we should be able to print such text via a modern top-end laser printer (1200x1200 DPI) and read it back with near-zero error via a modern scanner (also 1200x1200 DPI) and OCR suite (remembering that we got to choose a font that would be friendly to this).  We then get 48 characters per square inch.  At a very rough estimate, [there are around 200000 English words total](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language).  In ordinary usage, [the average word length is around 5 letters](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-number-of-letters-for-an-English-word), so we have around ten words.  The number of combinations of ten random English words is around 200000<sup>10</sup>, which is close to 2<sup>176</sup>, so by that measure we convey around 176 bits per square inch.  (And this is an overestimate, because the average length of *random* English words is closer to 7.5 letters.)

If we suppose that instead of English text we are printing arbitrary characters from a 128-element repertoire, i.e. using a base-128 encoding of arbitrary data, that goes up a bit to 336 bits / in<sup>2</sup>.  That's till not very dense.

But that kind of density is so 80s. We can fit more data by making the print very small. We'll use 2x2 binning for our printing to make the scan-back more reliable, and shrink the text to fit in, say, 12-pixel by 10-pixel boxes.  This gives us 50 lines of 60 characters per square inch, for an information density of 21000 bits  / in<sup>2</sup>.

That was much better, but still pretty measly.  We can get higher information density by looking at individual pixels instead of looking for a small set of patterns (character glyphs).  Supposing that we allocate a generous 10% of all pixels to supporting accurate orientation and registry of the pixel array, we still can convey over 320000 bits  / in<sup>2</sup>.

But wait, there's more! Now that we're allocating a fraction of all pixels to supporting registry of the pixel array, maybe we can go up to the full 1200x1200 pixel resolution of our equipment, thus reaching an information density of around 1.2M bits  / in<sup>2</sup>.

And we're not quite done.  The foregoing assumed black print, but top-end equipment can print and scan color at the same 1200x1200 resolution we're now talking about.  If we assume three color channels, and suppose that we can accurately resolve four levels per channel, then each of our pixels in fact carries 12 bits of information, bringing our density up to around 24M bits  / in<sup>2</sup>.

That's about the limit, I think.  One might push it a little farther by supposing a little better color resolution, but even supposing that 24-bit color could accurately be printed and read back, we're still at the same order of magnitude.  An 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper, printed edge to edge as described above, can accurately convey on the order of 300 million bytes.

So how does that compare to optical media?  Well, a standard-size optical disk has around 16 square inches of usable surface area.  A high-capacity CD-ROM provides around 700M bytes on that area.  Comparing that to your ad really emphasizes what a difference it makes how you measure.  Of course, that's an anachronistic comparison.  If we consider instead a quad-layer BDXL disk that crams 128G bytes in the same surface area, now were talking about more than a thousandfold difference in areal density between paper and optical media.